# Unable to parse json string in slim

Tags: php, json, slim

I am trying to develop rest full webservice using slim frame work.
There is a registration api to which my input data is

```
    {"firstname":"Rakhi",
    "lastname":"Krishnan",

     "language":{
     "english":["read","write"],
     "arabic":["read","speak"],
     "hindi":[]
   },
   "membership":{
   "involvement _level":["Atendant Only"]
    }
   }
```

I have parsed the input data using

```
$json = $request->getBody();
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

But when I tried to access  it gives me

```
$data['membership']['involvement _level']=array[][];
$data['membership']['involvement _level'][0]="Atendant Only" [][];
```

I don't know what is wrong in my code.Can any one please help me?

Comment: the question isn't clear. what you want to do? `$data['membership']['involvement _level'][0]` -> `Atendant Only`

Comment: yes.I need to access the value of  $data['membership']['involvement _level'].But it is not giving me the correct answer

Comment: `$data['membership']['involvement _level']` is an array. What you expect?

Comment: According to my json it will be  $data['membership']['involvement _level']= ["Atendant Only"]

Comment: yes it will. if you want just the first element of the array (`Atendant Only`): `echo $data['membership']['involvement _level'][0];` what's your question?

Comment: That is the answer we are expecting.But my programme giving me $data['membership']['involvement _level'][0] =Atendant Only [ ] [ ]  .Why this empty array is showing with my result ?

Comment: you see `Atendant Only [ ] [ ]`? can you provide a dump of `$data`? (`var_dump($data);`)

Comment: $data['membership']['involvement _level'] giving me an empty array

Comment: Can you show the actual code where your are printing `$data['membership']['involvement _level']`. Is that your complete JSON object? Methinks you are in a loop and maybe some other entries have an empty array for membership->involvement_level.

Comment: { "firstname":"Rahul","lastname":"Krishnan","gender":"male","agegroup":"Below 16 Years","nationality":"Rakhi"
,"idnumber":"1","email":"ras@s.com","country":"India","mobile":"9999999","language":{"english":["read"
,"write"],"arabic":["read","speak"],"hindi":[]},"membership":{"recovey_email":"s@agaze.in","username
 ":"Rahul","password ":"12345678","involvement _level":["Atendant Only"]}}
This is my json object

Comment: $json = $request->getBody();
$data = json_decode(var_dump($json), true);                                          $this->logger->addInfo("DATA4 :".$data['membership']['involvement _level']);